# How to indent long code in question or answer?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, code-formatting

Suppose I had to post 400 lines of code then will I have to indent all those lines by four spaces one by one or is there any other way ?

Comment: Actually I have to post 299 lines of css code to  ask a question.

Comment: Don't post 400 lines of code. If you have an issue, replicate it in a small block of code. You cannot expect anyone to wade through an entire program to look for issues.

Comment: Highlight, click the `{}` icon in the editor. Or click on the large orange question mark and read the instructions.

Comment: If you have that much could, I suggest you post it one a website like pastebin.com, or similar sites

Comment: @Juhana:I have read it but it doesn't address such case.I  am asking beacause it is really annoying to indent even 40 lines of code one by one

Comment: @InsaneCoder The reason is that in most cases you shouldn't even post that many lines of code. You can use something like Notepad++ to pre-format the code and then copy & paste but no one will read through 3-400 lines of code. Replicate your problem with as few lines as possible so people can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just select the code you want to indent, then click the [image] icon in the editor (or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>).

Comment: Or press ctrl-K